My variegated holly bush/tree
I have a variegated holly bush/tree dark green trimmed with light green leaves, but on a few branches I've noticed some pale green leaves one colour. Do l have to remove these plain leaves or will they have no impact on my tree. Someone said if l leave them on my tree, it will change from variegated to a plain colour. But I don't know if he was joking it's 30 yrs.

Pictures please!

It appears that that most of the variegated varieties are created with viruses.  These can revert to their non-variegated varieties.  Usually this happens on a branch basis, rather than single leaves.  However, it does no harm, if you want to be careful and you remove the plain leaves.
